# Section Scripts or regular <script> depending on Request Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a scenario where I would like to load scripts depending on the request type. For example, let's say I have this code:

```
@section scripts {
<script>
    $('#tabsContainer').InitializeTabs();
</scripts>
}
```

this loads perfectly fine when I want to load the full page. However, I have a thing where user can load the page partially as well. The scenario is like this:

```
public ActionResult Page() {
if (Request.IsAjax()) return PartialView();
return View()
}
```

The problem is, if it's being loaded partially, the script does not work because @section scripts does not work in partial. If I put it outside section scripts, it does not work on full view since I have my scripts on the bottom, and it's trying to run the script before the actual JavaScript files are being loaded.

I was wondering of a good way to implement this. I can move my scripts at top of the page and that should solve all problems. I could also have 2 different scripts but that might mean I have to write the same code twice.

Does anyone know a nice way to implement this? Maybe a Html helper that loads the script in @section scripts {} or in regular script tags depending on the Request type?

Basically, what is the proper way to write this:

```
@if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
    <text>
    @section scripts
    {
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            });
        </script>
    }
    </text>
}
else
{
    <text>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
                ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html'); // Update Google Analytics
            });
        </script>
    </text>
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Scripts should **never** be in partials. Place your scripts in the view or layout

Comment: I would like to disagree in this case. Sure, I agree they should **almost never** be in partial view. However, having a _FullView_ that can be rendered in _PartialView_, I feel like it may be okay? Could you maybe a define another way I can $('#tabs').Initialize() after the view is loaded (Whether Full or Partial. And beside the methods I posted above)?

Comment: Added an example to further illustrate my point.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply check that in view()

```
@if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
{
<script>
    alert('Partial view');
</script>
}
else
{
<script>
    alert('Main view');
</script>
}
```

Comment: I know but I stated in my post I would not like to have a duplicate script tag.

Answer (score 0):

An idea, which I haven't had the chance to test: Store some information on whether or not the request is an ajax request in the view (e.g. in a data attribute), and then, in your script test that value and do accordingly.

E.g.:

```
 <body data-isajaxrequest="@Request.IsAjaxRequest()">...</body>
```

And then the script:

```
$(function () {
    function InitializeTabs() {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
        if ($("body").data("isajaxrequest")) {
            // it's an ajax request
        } else {
            // not an ajax request
            ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html'); // Update Google Analytics
        }
    }

    $('#tabsContainer').InitializeTabs();
});
```

Place your logic as needed where the comments are. The actual script would go into the full view. As another poster mentioned, you shouldn't have scripts inside partial views.

Comment: Once again, this requires me to write duplicate script logic.

Comment: Without seeing what is in your InitializeTabs() functions, that's difficult to say. You could split out the logic that's separate to the ajax request and place that inside the if, and then everything that's in common outside the if statement. Based on what you've written in your post, I've updated my example. There's no duplicate code there.

Comment: I see that makes sense, however, the problem remains is that if it's NOT an Ajax request, it would need to be ran in @section scripts {}. This is more to do creating an MVC helper I believe, rather than something is the JS.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the use case. I made the assumption that, regardless if it's an ajax request or not, you would want to load the full view, and only the client-side logic (JavaScript) would be different. If that isn't the case, then my attempted answer likely won't help you much. However, if it is; move the JavaScript to a file, and include it in the scripts section for the view, and keep the data attribute on the view. It won't load until the document is ready, as `$(function () { ...` is short-hand for `$(document).ready(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try native JavaScipt way to this solution:

```js
var myFunction = function () {
   alert('myFunction called after 500ms.');
  // do a lot of stuff here
}

// and then call the function after the page is loaded
// let's supose an half second later:

setTimeout(myFunction, 500);
```